# Fixed Total Row When Sorting DataGridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have DATAGRIDVIEW CALLED ADVANCEDDATAGRIDVIEW
see this link
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DG.AdvancedDataGridView
okay ?
now I Filled this DGV FROM DATATABLE
Here the First Code : DT is A DATATABLE already has data

```
        With Form1.AdvancedDataGridView1
            .DataSource = DT
            Form1.BindingSource1.DataSource = .DataSource : Endwith
```

So now this DGV HAS DATA FROM DT
And I added BindingSource FROM TOOLBOX into Form1 And i Filled it From DATAGRIDVIEW.DataSource

The AdvancedDataGridview has already Filters Icons Like excel in Microsoft Office
But to make it Work You have to Write this Code in FilteringChange Event like this

```
    Private Sub AdvancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterStringChanged
    BindingSource1.Filter = AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString : End SUB
```

So now Added row in DT as like DT.rows.add() like this
so this ROW i Filled it By sum Of columns
ok.. Now look at the Image and see DGV NOW
[image: THIS IS AdvancedDataGriddView NOW]

So As You see there is Filter Icon up Wheni use it And filter data Like excel in MS  its work fine
But the last row ( TOTAL ROW )   become Not exist after Filtering
I am sorry for my bad English and description

---

THIS IS WHAT I Have Tried

---

```
Private Sub AdvancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterStringChanged

    Dim A, B As String
    A = CStr(AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString)
    B = A & " Or ItemName = 'total'"
    BindingSource1.Filter = B
```

Bro Thank you Very Much @dr.null
this work fine with me should I change anything ?

---

Here sorting issue

---

```
    Private Sub AdvancedDataGridView1_SortStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdvancedDataGridView1.SortStringChanged

    BindingSource1.Sort = AdvancedDataGridView1.SortString
    BindingSource1.Sort = "Sorting Asc"
```

on this code i added column named "Sorting" and i put all Column value = 0  except total row i made it = 1
now  this code dose not work with me correctly
have Anything to try ?

Comment: What is an Advanced DataGridView?  Document this question better.

Comment: it's A normal Datagridview But has Filter Icon at the Columns header ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15782053/14171304 ?

Comment: thank you @dr.null But  in this link   How i can use this "row.Tag = "Average"  can u explain ? where i should write and how ? there is no Row.tag Like this please explain

Comment: Please see the code Up ..  how I can Control Bindingsource.Filter  to show the last row in Bindingsource with every Filtering or sorting ?

Comment: Where did the _filtering_ requirement come from? It was about _sorting_ only! Anyways, I don't know about that advanced DGV thing and how it works. You need to clarify, what do you mean when you say a _total row_ in the `DataTable`. How do add it and calculate the total? Do you have it displayed in the grid when you set a filter? What does `AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString` property return? Just saying  _But when I sort THIS become useless._ doesn't help us to understand the problem. So, please edit and elaborate.

Comment: Ok @dr.null  I Updated My Post Again i hope if it better than before .. Thank you and sorry For my bad English

Comment: Get the `AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString` in a string variable and append `or yourTotalFieldName` to include the _total_ row, then assign the result to `BindingSource1.Filter` property. See [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-7.0).

Comment: WOOOOW MAN ... THANK you Very MUCH .. it's work .. Please check the last Update at the bottom See the code if there is something better please tell me

Comment: Very well. Feel free to post that as answer and accept it. Note, you don't need to do `A = CStr(AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString)`. The `.FilterString` property seems of type `string` already. If so, then just `A = AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString`. Well done.

Comment: thank you Bro Very Much I wish TO you Happy Life @dr.null

Comment: Bro . it's work with me fine when I filter Some Data But when I select ALL this error happened ((( Additional information: Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Or' operator. )) can You tell me what I have to DO ? @dr.null

Comment: `BindingSource1.Filter = $"({AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString}) Or (ItemName = 'total')"`. If this doesn't work, paste the `FilterString` value.

Comment: it's dosn't work bro i got this error (( Additional information: Syntax error: Missing operand after '' operator. )) Please tell me what do you mean by this ( paste the FilterString value @dr.null

Comment: this ?  (Convert([ItemAmount],System.String) IN (105))

Comment: this bro ? >> (( (Convert([ItemAmount],System.String) IN (100)) ))

Comment: Heeeeeey bro I fixed it hahah :)  thank you bro look at my answer Down .. really thank You very Much Bro . @dr.null

Comment: ahh. You are the man. Well done.

Comment: Ok bro ... Can you Help me with sorting ? i want to keep last row at the bottom .. if you don't mind .. please look at the last update for the post .. if you mind .. it's ok bro thank you anyway :) @dr.null

Comment: There's a [SortStringChanged](https://foxlearn.com/articles/advanced-filter-datagridview-in-csharp-121.html) event. Try to modify the `SortString`. Or, see the link in my first comment, and do the same. You can get the `total` row by converting the `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex1).DataBoundItem` and `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex2).DataBoundItem` to `DataRowView`, and do the same if the row is that `total` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by @dr.null

```
Private Sub AdvancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterStringChanged

    Dim A As String = AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString
    Dim B As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(A), A, A & " Or ItemName = 'total'")
    BindingSource1.Filter = B
```